# IIS Shared Configuration > HTTP Error 500.21

Tags: iis, .net-core, shared-config

I'm trying to run my `dotnet core` app in IIS **Clustered** environment. It runs perfectly when shared configuration is disabled. But soon I enable shared configuration, the application fails to start, and gives error:

`HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error`

`Handler "ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list`

I had been looking for the solution since few days, but nothing worked for me. Mostly posts at SO ask to install/reinstall .NET 4/4.5 etc, but this isn't applicable in my case, as it is already updated.

Following are the concerned section of my configuration
*(I can provide more if needed)*

**Web.config**:

```
...    
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" />
</handlers> ...
```

**Shared applicationHost.config**:

```
<handlers>
...
 <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
 <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
 <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
 <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
</handlers>
...
...
<modules>
  ...
  <add name="ApplicationInitializationModule" lockItem="true" />
  <add name="AspNetCoreModule" />
  <add name="RewriteModule" />
  <add name="ApplicationRequestRouting" />
</modules>
```

Is there something I am missing?
The app runs fine when disable shared configuration of IIS, or when run through .exe. So I believe the required features are installed. Is there any feature/package specifically required for shared configuration case? Please guide.

Comment: Have you changed your anonymous user and application pool to a domain user that have permission to access the shared path? Besides, have you tried this %windir%\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\aspnet\_regiis.exe -i?

Comment: #1. Yes, the domain user has permissions. #2. Yes, but it said something like 'operation is not valid because it is already up to date' (not exact words). I doubt this registration thing is only for older versions of IIS, ans SO posts which mention of this are from around 2012, 2014, etc.